# How do I insert this jQuery slider plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the HTML and CSS in just fine. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to insert the jQuery and plugin correctly. I am somewhat new to jQuery and JavaScript. I must be placing these incorrectly and I am confused on how to do this. It seems so simple, but I am not seeing it.

Here is a reference to where I have gotten the code from:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Infinite-Looping-Scroller-Plugin-With-jQuery-loopmovement.html

Below are the links to the JS that I've placed in the bottom of the HTML

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.loopmovement.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="js/jquery.loopmovement.js"></script>
```

[As you can see the HTML and CSS are fine, but nothing works as it should. It's not moving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUwST.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Need your code, we shouldn't have to guess and we can't read minds.

Comment: What exactly are wanting me to post? I think it might be a bit ridiculous to post the entire HTML, CSS and JS files.

I'm asking where I should place the code that's on the link. I have steps 1 and 2 placed correctly, but 3 and 4 are confusing to me.

Comment: What you are asking is fundamental to web development and it's more expedient to correct what you've already done rather than explain everything not knowing what you are already capable of doing. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to make a [mcve]. When you say steps 1, 2, 3, and 4...where are these steps coming from a book?

Comment: So if I asked how I should build a house and I think it's 4 steps to do so, should I expect the carpenter to conform to these so called 4 steps when I don't even know how to hammer a nail?

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided? If you look at the page and scroll down just the slightest bit it lists 4 steps. Step 1 being the HTML, step 2 being the CSS and steps 3 & 4 are the JS.
I agree that it looks, seems and probably is fundamental. I however haven't passed that stage of the fundamentals when it comes to JS.

Comment: No, I didn't look at the link and neither will the majority of people that see that there's no effort to conform to the way things are done here. All you have to do is browse the first half of the first page of questions to get an idea of what is expected of a post. The burden is on the one with the question not the one with the answer.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to this. Please don't mistake my words with attitude. I edited it with more information, the JS that it says to link in the HTML and a picture. I hope this will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#box1').loopmovement({
  'direction':'top',  
  'speed':20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-Looping-Scroller-Plugin-With-jQuery-loopmovement/jquery.loopmovement.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-Looping-Scroller-Plugin-With-jQuery-loopmovement/jquery.loopmovement.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">
<div id="box1">
 <div class="content toLeft"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> This is Item 1</div>
    <div class="content toLeft"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> This is Item 2</div>
    <div class="content toLeft"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> This is Item 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Would you please refer my above code?

Comment: Well it obviously works for you, but I don't get how. You have different links than I do. Do the links it provides for me not work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should:

1 - download the javascript files from the plugin site

2 - save them inside a 'js' folder on your project (create one if you already didn't)

3 - link the files in your html using usual `<script src="">` code.

That can make your plugin work.

Comment: What I don't get is if I'm supposed to copy and paste this stuff at the bottom of the HTML so that it links to it or paste some of the actual JavaScript at the bottom of the HTML rather than link it.

Comment: You should link it. It will make your code cleaner with better performance.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I did edit my question above with more information. Maybe that'll help.